Passing environment variable to vscode remote terminal
I have remote vscode server and I want to pass an environment variable to it
It work with SSH but doesn't work with vscode remote
I've setted up
local ~/.ssh/config:
Host <dev-server>
    SendEnv MY_VARIABLE

remote /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
AcceptEnv *

When I'm using raw SSH (without vscode) everything works and I have my variable passed
But when I'm using vscode remote it doesn't work
Should I put something special to /Users/kungasc/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json or something else to make it work?
